# Android phone will not show map (only blank map)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, codenameone

I'm currently testing out the Google Maps feature on Android using CodenameOne. When I open the app in the simulator, the app loads fine however when I load it onto an old Android phone of mine, it just loads into a blank white screen (with the little Google logo in the bottom corner). Also, the regular Google Maps app on the phone itself works fine. What could I be doing wrong?

The code in my single class is as follows:

```
package com.example.willheard27.maptest

import com.codename1.googlemaps.MapContainer;
import com.codename1.maps.Coord;
import com.codename1.ui.Command;
import com.codename1.ui.Dialog;
import com.codename1.ui.Display;
import com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.events.ActionEvent;
import com.codename1.ui.events.ActionListener;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager;
import com.codename1.ui.util.Resources;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainClass {

private Form current;

public void init(Object context) {
    try {
        Resources theme = Resources.openLayered("/theme");
        UIManager.getInstance().setThemeProps(theme.getTheme(theme.getThemeResourceNames()[0]));
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void start() {
    if(current != null){
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    Form hi = new Form();
    hi.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    final MapContainer cnt = new MapContainer();
    hi.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, cnt);

    hi.show();
}

public void stop() {
    current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
}

public void destroy() {

}

}
```

Comment: This is always an api key problem. Look in the logs for an error related to the api key.

Comment: When you run app in phone then it was in debug mode or you run signed apk?

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="Your api key" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Make sure about api key in manifest file and that should be valide. you can get it from google developer console page.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the API key is defined correctly in the build hints as explained in the project page.

Make sure the certificate key is also defined in the google cloud console section to enabling V2 maps.

Make sure you are building with a certificate which is obviously required for this case.

If there is still an issue connect the device using a cable and launch the DDMS tool from the Android SDK. You should see an output of the SHA1 value and package names make sure they match the values in your google cloud console entries.